How to Plot a Colored Vector Field Using Quiver on matlab?
This is the picture associated with my code but I want the vector fields to be in different coloursThis is my code:
t = readtable('B00001.txt','ReadVariableNames',false);
mat = readmatrix('B00001.txt');
X = mat(:,1);
Y = mat(:,2);
U = mat(:,3);
V = mat(:,4);
quiver(X,Y,U,V);
colormap(jet(256));
axis equal

I used the colormap function, but it did not help with making the vectors in different colours

How do you expect the data to be coloured? We can't run this code because we don't have your local data, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] (with arbitrary data) and an illustration of your desired output?

@Wolfie I just added a picture of my current plot that shown the vector fields are only in blue and not in different colours

That doesn't really answer my question, what should the colours represent? One per field? A [mcve] would make it easier to adapt your code into an answer

1.- MATLAB functions quiver and quiver3
as they are now, only a single [R G B] is accepted to colour the entire field of arrows with the same colour. R G B values all within [0 1].
I tried to feed a size 3 by nx*ny column of custom [R G B] values but no way, only one colour for the entire field.
Rewording : quiver does not allow colour maps on the arrows
However,
2.- J.Krimmer's functions quiverC2D and quiverC3D available here
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58527-quiver-magnitude-dependent-color-in-2d-and-3d?s_tid=srchtitle
These funcions that allow to do precisely feeding a custom colour map, that goes then proportional with the magnitude of the arrows ONLY,.
This magnitude-only is probably may be a limitation, because you may want to make colouring as function of MAGNITUDE as well as ANGLE.
3 -
quiverc by B.Dano does exactly what you need
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3225-quiverc
4.-
Uquiver by B.Dano
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24080-uquiver?s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_2_quiverC2D
keeps all vectors on same size but allows custom colouring of the entire field of arrows.
